# How can I point admin action method to other than `indexAction()`?

Tags: module, magento-1, admin-controller, custom-menu

In my module, I am setting up my menu like this.

```
 <menu>
     <catalog>
        <children>
            <rkt_arattr translate="title" module="rkt_arattr">
                <title>Manage My Custom Attribute</title>
                <sort_order>100</sort_order>
                <children>
                    <install_attr translate="title" module="rkt_arattr">
                        <title>Install My Attribute</title>
                        <action>adminhtml/catalog_arattr_install</action>
                        <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                    </install_attr>
                </children>
            </rkt_arattr>
        </children>
     </catalog>
 </menu>
```

The code that you need to concentrate is `action`

```
 <action>adminhtml/catalog_arattr_install</action>
```

For this value, my url looks like this

> www.mydomain.com/admin/catalog_arattr_install/index/key/[key_value]

As per this ulr, Magento expects a controller setup like this.

File : `app/code/local/Namespace/Modulename/controllers/Adminhtml/Catalog/Araattr/InstallController.php`

```
<?php
class Namespace_Modulename_Adminhtml_Catalog_Arattr_InstallController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Contorller_Action
{
     public function indexAction()
     {

     }
}
```

However this is not what I want.. I need my url parse like this.

> www.mydomain.com/admin/catalog_arattr/install/key/[key_value]

Means I want the below method get called when click on the menu

File : `app/code/local/Namespace/Modulename/controllers/Adminhtml/Catalog/ArattrController.php`

```
<?php
class Namespace_Modulename_Adminhtml_Catalog_ArattrController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Contorller_Action
{
     public function installAction()
     {

     }
}
```

But it seems that, magento always looks for `indexAction()` when we setup a menu.

***Is there any way to direct to my custom action when click on the menu ?***

Comment: Good Question......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be as simple as adding extra parts to the `action` node.

```
<action>adminhtml/your_controller/your_action</action>
```

Check out how the downloads part of the admin section works.

```
<action>adminhtml/report_product/downloads</action>
```

Here the controller is `Mage_Adminhtml_Report_ProductController` and the action is `downloadsAction`

Comment: I have already tried `adminhtml/catalog_arattr/install/`. It didnt work. I will try once more and let you know

Comment: My bad. I just tried `adminhtml/catalog_arattr/install/` in wrong adminhtml.xml file. That is why it didnt work. I feel the question is bad now :-(

Comment: @programmer_rkt for me the question is still a good one. As it is not so common to do so might not be many other resources on how to do it.

Comment: Doesn't matter as long as you got it sorted - leave this info here though, will certainly prove to explain things to others in the future.

Comment: @JonathanHussey : I was going to comment on your answer about my stupidity. David is right. This question is not a common one. I have searched this before I post here. So I think it may help future visitors. So I am leaving this question as it is. Also david is answered first and so he won the match !. :-)

Comment: Yep no worries.

Comment: You should know that I love this part of your answer `<action>adminhtml/report_product/downloads</action>`. This is what I missed. I have searched entire `Mage_Catalog` module for any clue. But didnt get it. This part increased my believe that "Look into the core. Everytyhing is there." :-)

Answer (score 2):

Your `action` path should be `adminhtml/catalog_arattr/install` to define the `install` section of the path as the action.  Each `/` slash separates the module, the controller and then the action so as you only have 1 slash the action is assumed to be `indexAction()`.  With the above URL the request will target the `Namespace_Modulename_Adminhtml_Catalog_ArattrController` and inside that `installAction()`.  You will of course need to change the location of the controller to one directory higher up.